# How to get a return of specific column and relative row in Excel and use it in other formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For example, when I insert this formula `="E"&ROW()` in a certain cell, I get E52 in return.
Then I want to use this formula within a formula `=IF(("E"&ROW())="EXAMPLE",Yes)`, but it just doesn't work and returns the value as FALSE/#NAME?

Is there any way to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

`"E"&ROW()` will be equal to something like `"E52"` then different to `"EXAMPLE"`.

You should try `INDIRECT("E"&ROW())`.

Comment: Hi Frédéric,
You just saved my life.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

With `=IF(("E"&ROW())="EXAMPLE",Yes)` you're basically asking whether E52 is equal to EXAMPLE, which it isn't. You need to combine it with the [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("E"&ROW())="EXAMPLE",Yes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to be overlooking the obvious. 
If `"E"&ROW()` evaluates to `E52`,
then the `="E"&ROW()` formula must be in Row 52. 
So, I guess you want to reference the value
in Column `E` of the *current* row — as the question title suggests. 
You want to be able to copy your formula to Row 42
and have it automagically reference `E42`.

Excel does this for you automatically. 
Just use `E52` in a formula ***in Row 52**,*
and Excel will automatically change it to `E83` if you copy it to Row 83.